# Inserting PHP objects to database

Tags: php

```
<?php
 class Prof {
    function get_block($lines, $prof_num) {
    $reserve = 200;
    $strings = implode("", $lines);
    $start_line = preg_grep("/1\.$prof_num\.1\./m", $lines);
    $prof_num+=1;
    $end_line = preg_grep("/1\.$prof_num\.1\./m", $lines);
    $prof_num-=1;
    $start_pos = mb_strpos($strings, end($start_line)); 
    $end_pos = mb_strpos($strings, end($end_line));
    $finalContent = mb_substr($strings, $start_pos-$reserve, $end_pos-$start_pos+$reserve);
    $from = "1.$prof_num";
    $prof_num+=1;
    $to = "1.$prof_num";
    $cutted = mb_substr($finalContent, strpos($finalContent, $from), strpos($finalContent, $to));
    $cutted = preg_replace("/$to\..*/", "", $cutted);
//        echo $cutted;
//        $this->get_id($cutted);
//        $this->get_name($cutted);
}

function get_id($txt) { //gettind id
    $txt = explode("\n", $txt);
    $id = preg_grep("/\d\.\sCode\s/", $txt);
    $id = preg_replace("/\d\.\sCode\s\–\s/","", $id);
    $id = preg_replace("/\t/", "",$id);
    $id = preg_replace("/\.\s+/", "",$id);
    foreach($id as $item) {
        echo $item ."\n";
    }
}

function get_name($txt) { //getting name
    $txt = explode("\n", $txt);
    $name = preg_grep("/\sName/", $txt);
    $name = preg_replace("/\d\.\sName\–\s/","",$name);
    $name = preg_replace("/\t/", "",$name);
    $name = preg_replace("/\.\s+/", "",$name);
    foreach($name as $item) {
        echo $item ."\n";
    }
}

Obj1 = new Prof();
Obj1 -> get_name(get_block(file('text.txt'))); //ERROR HERE!!!!!!!!
```

How can I get to get_id and get_name through get_block method?

```
- get_block gets me the whole text from text file, starting from line number $prof_num. 
- get_id gets me the id from the get_block text block. get_name just gets the name from 
get_block.
```

I need to write these methods (id and name) to my database, but as I know, I can't do it, if I only manage to get text block with get_block.

Pls, ask me if something, maybe I just can't explain it. :D

Comment: you would be better posting the actual code rather than the pseudo code which technically is incorrect

Comment: Define the Class properly and maybe we can help you

Comment: Look up the `$this->` [RTM - Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)

Comment: for me u need study OOP php...

Comment: Posted the full code.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
Obj1 -> get_name(get_block(file('text.txt')))
```

The function `get_block()` is not defined, it is a method of your `Pro` class.

So you would need:

```
$Obj1->get_name($Obj1->get_block(file('text.txt')));
```

or, if it is a static method:

```
$Obj1->get_name(Pro::get_block(file('text.txt')));
```

Also note that `get_block()` is defined as a method that takes 2 parameters, something that looks like a string (based on the name...) and a number (based on the name...). So sending it only an array - the return value of `file()` - will also fail.